# How to use nuxtjs3 useFetch pick parameter for arrays or make a deep pick?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In my nuxtjs3 project, I would like to pick the data I get from an API.

In this case, I use jsonPlaceholder. I have no problem when it comes to picking data from an object:

```
const { data: useFetchOnly } = await useFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {
    pick: ['title']
  })

console.log({useFetchOnly})
```

but when I try to pick data from an array of objects, I do not know, how to do it. I tried with the following, but without success:

```
const { data: useFetchArray } = await useFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/', {
    pick: ['title']
  })

console.log({useFetchArray})
```

Any ideas on how to solve it?

The documentation, that I found is not helping in this case:
[LINK](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you need `transform` instead of `pick`:

> If you need more control or map over several objects, you can use the
> `transform` function to alter the result of the query.

So your final code should look like this:

```
const { data} = await useFetch('url', {
    transform: (r) => r.map(({ title }) => title);
})
```

Also keep in mind that:

> Both pick and transform don't prevent the unwanted data from being
> fetched initially. But they will prevent unwanted data from being
> added to the payload transferred from server to client.

You can learn more in [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#minimize-payload-size).

Comment: Why not write it as `{ transform: (r) => r.map(({ title }) => title) }`?